# singleton subclass constructor errors

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I Tried to subclass a singleton and i encountered the error while i tried to print from the derived class constructor.

mysingleton.h

```
#ifndef mysingleton_h
#define mysingleton_h
#include <iostream>
class mysingleton{
  public:
   static mysingleton* singletoninstance; //The one and only one instance
   static mysingleton* getinstance();
   virtual void dosomething() = 0 ;

 protected:
   mysingleton(const mysingleton&);
   ~mysingleton();

   public:
      mysingleton(){

      }//Prevent clients from creating new singleton

   };



class mysingleton_child:public mysingleton
{
  public:
    virtual void dosomething() {
       std::cout <<"In Child Class \n";
     }
    mysingleton_child()
   {
    //   std::cout <<"In Child Class \n";

   }
~mysingleton_child();
};
```

mysingleton.cpp

```
#include "mysingleton.h"
mysingleton* mysingleton::singletoninstance = 0;

mysingleton* mysingleton ::  getinstance()
{
  if( !singletoninstance )
    singletoninstance = new  mysingleton_child();
  return singletoninstance;  
}
```

main func :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mysingleton.h"
int main ()
{
   mysingleton *pointer  = mysingleton::getinstance();
   pointer->dosomething();
}
```

I get the below error when i uncomment the line from mysingleton_child constructor

> //   std::cout <<"In Child Class \n";

Error:

> Error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "mysingleton::~mysingleton()", referenced from:
>     mysingleton_child::mysingleton_child()

Why am i  not able to write anything in the constructor ?
Is the derived constructor called , or just the base classes constructor is called?
Also, when i make the base classes destructor public everything seems to work fine. 
But if we have a public destructor , any would destroy the singleton.

Can you please help me with the explanation and make me understand better.

Comment: Singletons are an anti-pattern (just glorified global variables). You'll be much happier in the long term, if you just forget about them. Don't use singletons - please!

Comment: And *subclassing* `mysingleton`? That fundamentally violates the promise that there will only be one instance of `mysingleton`.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with singletons. You would have seen that if you'd created a [mcve].

Comment: @user2357112: Well, you still have only one instance of the singleton, just it's one instance per derived object :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this line you allow everyone to get the instance of your singleton directly:

```
static mysingleton* singletoninstance; //The one and only one instance
```

So the next line doesn't have sense:

```
static mysingleton* getinstance();
```

But the problem is that you declared copy constructor and destructor, but didn't defined them in your .cpp file:

```
mysingleton(const mysingleton&);
   ~mysingleton();
```

You also declared ordinary constructor and made it `public`. It's a mistake. You can look at `Gang of Four` book to understand singletons better. Also read `StackOverflow` articles about why singletons can be bad. Just google "singleton stack overflow bad".

Comment: why ? Its a static function through which we are trying to retrieve the instance? So there is no need of a function ? Can you please explain why a static function is not needed for a singleton.

Comment: You need a static function to obtain an instance of your singleton. But you don't need to declare a pointer to the instance as public member. Usually it's declared as private.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared ~mysingleton() and ~mysingleton_child() in class definition, you should provide a definition of them.